# Evaluation of $ \int_0^\infty\frac{x^{1/3}\log x}{x^2+1}\ dx $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

The following is an exercisein complex analysis:

> Use contour integrals with $-\pi/2<\operatorname{arg} z<3\pi/2$ to compute
>   $$
> I:=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{1/3}\log x}{x^2+1}\ dx.
> $$

I don't see why the branch $-\pi/2<\operatorname{arg} z<3\pi/2$ would work. Let
$$
f(z)=\frac{z^{1/3}\log z}{z^2+1}.
$$
Denote $\Gamma_r={re^{it}:0\leq t\leq \pi}$. One can then consider a contour consisting of $\Gamma_R$, $\Gamma_r$, and $[-R,-r]\cup[r,R]$. The integral along $[r,R]$ will give $I$. But without symmetries, how could one deal with the integral along $[-R,-r]$?

Comment: Just for clarification, what do you mean by "without symmetries, how could one..." ? I think I understand, but I would rather ask to be clear.

Comment: Well, when one integrates along $[-R,-r]$, one gets the integral along $[r,R]$ *plus* another one which is due to the argument $\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To first answer the question in the OP regarding the applicability of a branch cut along the negative imaginary axis, we note that we can certainly evaluate the integral of $\frac{z^a \log(z)}{z^2+1}$ over the proposed contour as

$$\begin{align}\oint_C \frac{z^a \log(z)}{z^2+1} &=\int_r^R \frac{x^a\log(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx-\int_{r}^{R}\frac{e^{i\pi a}x^a(\log(x)+i\pi )}{x^2+1}\,dx\\\\
&+\int_{0}^\pi \frac{R^ae^{ia\phi}(\log(R)+i\phi)}{R^2e^{i2\phi}+1}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\&-\int_{0}^\pi \frac{r^ae^{ia\phi}(\log(r)+i\phi)}{r^2e^{i2\phi}+1}\,ire^{i\phi}\,d\phi\end{align}$$

Proceeding, for $0<a<1$, the third and fourth integrals vanish as $r\to 0$ and $R\to \infty$ and the first and second become in the limit

$$(1-e^{i\pi a})\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a\log(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx-i\pi e^{i\pi a}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{x^2+1}\,dx$$

which requires evaluation of two integrals.   In that which follows, we present a different way forward for which we evaluate a single integral only.  To that end, we proceed.

> Note that the integral of interest can be expressed as
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/3}\log(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx=\left. \frac{d}{da}\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{x^2+1}\,dx\right)\right|_{a=1/3} }\tag 1$$

Therefore, we proceed by evaluating the integral $I(a)$ given by

$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{x^2+1}\,dx \tag 2$$

for $0<a<1$.

We move to the complex plane.  Let $C$ be the classical key-hole contour with the keyhole along the positive real axis.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \frac{z^a}{z^2+1}\,dz&=\int_\epsilon^R \frac{x^a}{x^2+1}\,dx+\int_R^\epsilon \frac{e^{i2\pi a}x^a}{x^2+1}\,dx\\\\
&+\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{R^ae^{ia\phi}}{R^2e^{i2\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi+\int_{2\pi}^0 \frac{\epsilon e^{ia\phi}}{\epsilon^2 e^{i2\phi}+1}\,i\epsilon^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=(1-e^{i2\pi a})\int_\epsilon^R \frac{x^a}{x^2+1}\,dx\\\\
&+\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{R^ae^{ia\phi}}{R^2e^{i2\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi-\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\epsilon e^{ia\phi}}{\epsilon^2 e^{i2\phi}+1}\,i\epsilon^{i\phi}\,d\phi \tag 3
\end{align}$$

As $R\to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$ the second and third integrals on the right-hand side of $(3)$ vanish while the first integral becomes $(1-e^{i2\pi a})I(a)$ as given in $(2)$.

Next, applying the residue theorem we find that

$$J(a)=2\pi i \left(\frac{e^{i\pi a/2}}{2i}+\frac{e^{i3\pi a/2}}{-2i}\right)=-2\pi i e^{i\pi a}\sin(\pi a/2) \tag 4$$

Putting together the limit of $(3)$ and the result from $(4)$ reveals

$$I(a)=\frac{\pi}{2\cos(\pi a/2)} $$

from which we find that

$$I'(1/3)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Finally, from $(1)$ find that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/3}\log(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$$

Comment: (+1). Nice work. Let me respectfully point out that the question does look like it asks to test the skill level with complex logarithms. One advantage of your approach is that it introduces the keyhole contour and the residues at the two poles.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Marko, thank you!  Much appreciative.   I've edited and added a preamble that answers the direct question in the OP.  +1 for your comment and +1 for your solution.  -Mark

Comment: Just a quick question. On the negative imaginary axis as asked for by the OP we get $$\frac{1}{\exp(-i\pi/2)^2 x^2+1} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$ which, when substituted, is not a multiple of the target integral. It's possible that I misinterpreted the question and that OP means to choose the branch of the logarithm only and keep the slot on the positive real axis, which looks difficult as well.

Comment: The OP is not integrating on the imaginary axis.  The chosen branch cut is there, but it might have well been taken as the ray $\phi = 5\pi/4$.  The OP is integrating in the upper-half plane along the real axis and an infinite semicirlcle centered at the origin.

Comment: I see it now, I understand what you're doing, thanks and sorry for the trouble. Looks fine.

Comment: @markoriedel Marko, No trouble at all.  You're one ofthe "good guys" on MSE.  -Mark

Comment: Nice to know that we have a quality answer for the OP now, My answer was written so as to be first.

Comment: @marko Yes.  Two different approaches that yield the same result.  That is one of the things about analysis that still intrigues and makes it so cool.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch of a  possible argument. Use the branch  with the argument from
zero to $2\pi$ of the logarithm, the function

$$f(z) = \frac{\exp(1/3\log z)\log z}{z^2+1}$$

and a  keyhole contour  with the slot  aligned with the  positive real
axis.

The sum of the residues at $z=\pm i$ is (take care to use the chosen branch of the logarithm in the logarithm as well as in the power/root)
$$\rho_1+\rho_2 = \frac{1}{8}\,\pi \,\sqrt {3}-\frac{5}{8}\,i\pi.$$

Now below the keyhole we get

$$\exp(1/3\log z)\log z
= \exp(2\pi i/3) \exp(1/3\log x)
(\log x + 2\pi i).$$

Introduce the labels
$$J = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/3}\log x}{x^2+1} dx$$

and

$$K = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/3}}{x^2+1} dx$$

The contribution from the line below the slot is

$$-\exp(2\pi i/3) J - 2\pi i\exp(2\pi i/3) K.$$

We evaluate $K$ and obtain

$$K = \pi\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}.$$

Solving $$2\pi i (\rho_1+\rho_2) =
(1-\exp(2\pi i/3)) J 
- 2\pi i\exp(2\pi i/3) \pi\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

we obtain

$$J =\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

**Remark.**
The evaluation of $K$ is recursive and uses the same contour.

We get for the two residues
$$\rho_1+\rho_2 = -\frac{1}{4} i\sqrt {3}-\frac{1}{4}$$

and hence we have 
$$2\pi i (\rho_1+\rho_2) =
(1-\exp(2\pi i/3)) K$$

which we may solve for $K$ to get the value cited above.

**Remark II.**  The fact that the circular  component vanishes follows
by the ML inequality which gives in the case of evaluating $J$

$$2\pi R \times \frac{R^{1/3}\log R}{R^2-1}
\rightarrow\ 0$$

as  $R\rightarrow\infty.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does one have to use a different branch than the one in OP?

Comment: The quality above is rather middling (written so as to be quick). Yes you do use a different branch, namely the one with the cut on the positive real axis and argument zero to $2\pi.$

Comment: Hmm. So do you think calculating with the $(-\pi/2,3\pi/2)$ branch would be rather difficult?

Comment: Well for starters one would need to account for the contribution from the singularity at $-i$ which would end up on the branch cut. Let me remind you that there are several experts on the subject at this site who will see your question I hope. I have omitted some of the complex number algebra as it does not add to an understanding of the subject. You need to implement your own logarithm if you are using a CAS or else you will most likely get the values from the classic $[-\pi,\pi)$ branch.