# Value of integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^p \ln(x)}{x^2 + 1}\,dx\;?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How can we solve this integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^p \ln(x)}{x^2  + 1}dx\;?$$

The result is given to be $$\frac{\pi^2}{4} \frac{\sin^2(\pi p/2)}{\cos(\pi p /2)}.$$

But I have no idea how to come at this integral solution. Any help?

At least I see method of substitution is not going to help. The denominator some how reminds me of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ but still alas. The improper integral hints me to use complex analysis stuff.

Comment: Your result depends on $x$ ? This is non sense. Moreover, I think it should depend on $p$. And please precise who is $p$. Obviously it cannot be any number.

Comment: Sorry, I messed it, by thinking about sec(x) and tan(x)

Comment: What values can $p$ attain? For a lot of $p$ this integral does not converge.

Comment: For $-1<p<1$, we have $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^p\log x}{x^2+1}\,dx=\frac{d}{dp}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^p}{x^2+1}\,dx=\frac{d}{dp}\frac{\pi}{2\cos(\pi p/2)}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\frac{\sin(\pi p/2)}{\cos^2(\pi p/2)}.$$

Comment: Lightening!!!!!

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761922/evaluation-of-int-0-infty-fracx1-3-log-xx21-dx) and its answers could be helpful.

Comment: @BAYMAX: are you sure it's $\sin^2$ in the numerator and $\cos$ in the denominator?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the integral$$\mathfrak{I}(p)=\int\limits_0^{\infty}\mathrm dx\,\frac {x^p}{1+x^2}$$Make the transformation $x\mapsto\tan x$ to get$$\mathfrak{I}(p)=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\mathrm dx\,\tan^px=\frac 12\Gamma\left(\frac {1+p}2\right)\Gamma\left(\frac {1-p}2\right)=\frac {\pi}2\sec\left(\frac {\pi p}2\right)$$Now differentiate with respect to $p$ to get the answer.